# How to cut a part of a page from one pdf file and draw it on another pdf file with Java?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, pdf

Having 2 PDF documents with contents, the first PDF document contains only 1 page with a footer. It is required to extract this footer as a content or an image from the first document (the exact coordinates and size of the content to be extracted are known) and then print it as content or an image on each page of another PDF document.

It is expected to be implemented in Java.

In adding more details, these PDF documents were created while converting them from HTML, using Selenium, which was also used to extract height, width, and coordinates.

Comment: You could try itext or pdfbox. An introduction on both is given [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pdf-file-read) but you'd need to explore the API's available in each to see what's possible

Comment: Another option may be to reverse engineer the footer and write it in FO. You could then use [apache fop](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to generate PDF from FO

Comment: What have you tried yet, what is the blocker now?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have tried iText and PDFBox from apache, but I just cant find a proper functionality for it. 
With apache PDFBox you can draw the PDFXImageObject on the page, but I need to somehow cut the pdf page and convert to this object, or  convert to Image and then cut. ChatGPT and Gemini is a shit, they just invent some methods which dont exist